# Is there any limit to the size of PUT/POST data while indexing documents in Elastic Search via Http call?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, http-post, httpurlconnection, elasticsearch-5

I am creating a heavy-update search application using Elastic Search 5.0.1,  wherein hundreds of thousands of records are indexed into elastic search. This happens every few seconds for multiple indices from my Java client using [HttpURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). I am using [elastic search's Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) for which I create a single PUT entity containing line separated JSON strings like below (as shown in the [Bulk API docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html)):

```
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
....
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
```

But, when the number of documents exceeds a certain limit, I get the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Error writing to server
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:582)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:594)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1216)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:379)
```

As I could check [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/151090/is-there-a-maximum-size-for-content-of-an-http-post), there is no theoretical limit to the PUT data size, but only the restrictions imposed by the client and server.

Does Elastic Search service impose any such restrictions? If yes, what are those limits and how this case can be better handled (modify server limits or batch the queries)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard limit, as pointed out from the [official guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bulk.html#_how_big_is_too_big), one should try until the "right" limits are found.

From this link you can see:

> Try indexing typical documents in batches of increasing size. When performance starts to drop off, your batch size is too big. A good place to start is with batches of 1,000 to 5,000 documents or, if your documents are very large, with even smaller batches.

But note:

> One thousand 1KB documents is very different from one thousand 1MB documents. A good bulk size to start playing with is around 5-15MB in size.

Here you can find [official tips](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tune-for-indexing-speed.html) for the performance optimization of the bulk requests